# How to send a variable with Laravel Auth login?

Tags: laravel, variables, authentication, laravel-authorization

I have used Laravel Auth. I want to send a variable from the login controller but login controller just has a redirect function. How can I send a variable with that redirect function... Like as

```
$topics = Topic::orderBy('start_date','ASC')->where('status',1)->get();
    return view('Admin.topic',compact('topics'));
```

Comment: Login controller has a redirect so sending view data will not work unless you store them in the session and retrieve them in the route you are redirected to. However you can just retrieve them in that route anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your `LoginController` you have a `trait` named `AuthenticatesUsers` which has bunch of methods that you can override them in your `LoginController` I think this method will solve your problem

```
/**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }
```

Comment: it is not working. I have put my login in the authenticated method. I'm using return view in this method where topics is a variable:  `
        return view('home',compact('topics'));